# Rotation in 3D coordinate system

Tags: python, opencv, 3d, physics, mediapipe

I have some fixed points and axes in the 3D coordinate system.
I compute the angle between these axes and some specific points in t = 0, and I am trying to predict their coordinates in any t knowing that my points rotate according to one particular ax with an alpha angle. How can I compute the predicted coordinates using rotation matrices?
I tried something like this :

```
def rotate(axis=(1., 0., 0.), angle=0.0, radians=None):
    """ 4x4 rotation matrix around 'axis' with 'angle' degrees or 'radians' """
    x, y, z = normalized(vec(axis))
    s, c = sincos(angle, radians)
    nc = 1 - c
    return np.array([[x*x*nc + c,   x*y*nc - z*s, x*z*nc + y*s, 0],
                     [y*x*nc + z*s, y*y*nc + c,   y*z*nc - x*s, 0],
                     [x*z*nc - y*s, y*z*nc + x*s, z*z*nc + c,   0],
                     [0,            0,            0,            1]], 'f')
.
.
.
.

x = item.x
y = item.y
shape = image.shape 
relative_x = int(x * shape[1])
relative_y = int(y * shape[0])
theta = atan(relative_y/relative_x)


predicted = [np.array([200,200,0,0]),np.array([400,400,0,0])] # an example of pts
r = rotate(axis=(1., 0 , 0 ), radians=theta)
predicted = [r @ predicted[0] ,r @ predicted[1]]
```

but the result is false. Is the computation of the rotation matrix valid? Thank you

Comment: 3D transformations can be quite complicated. Can you draw the setting, so that camera, object, axis, rotation center, rotation axis, origin etc. of your setting are shown? Also tell how you checked the result and show result as well as expected result.

Comment: Thank you @Micka for the answer. I have a simple 3D image where I knew the coordinates of some points and I am trying to predict the others. My rotation axis for example is ox and theta is calculated using atan formula. The results are shown is the image using `cv2.circle(image, (x,y), radius=15, color=(0, 0, 0), thickness=1)` where x and y are the predicted coordinates computed. The problem that the image for the moment is (static) and thetha is around 0. But the new coordinates are dynamic.

Comment: so for theta around 0 it is working, but if you want to change the rotation center it does not work? A sketch/visualization of your setting would really help ;)